# React JS Rest Api Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have made a simple application that supports CRUD operations on a student model(Get Student by ID, Delete Student by ID etc). Can someone help with how to make a simple restful api call to the endpoint(http://ip:port/allstudents) and render the obtained json format in React UI?
My code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
Getfunction() {
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
<button>b1</button>
</a>
}
render() {
return (
<div>
  <button id='b1'
    style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}}
    onClick={() => this.Getfunction()}>
    Get!
  </button>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Where can I put my restful api call to query and how exactly?

Comment: Just google it. You can use fetch for Rest API

Comment: I have done that before posting the question here. But the examples were not clear enough.I have edited my question to be more precise!

Comment: You might want to look at how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) React is a library for building user interfaces, And hence you don't use 'react' to do computation and stuff like network calls. Feel free to use functionalities such as async/await or use fetch to collect data from a url. Look at the documentation for fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

Comment: This is such a common problem (that I and many of us have struggled with when working with CRUD apis) that I created a library to try to simplify this for all of us: https://github.com/DigitalGlobe/jetset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to make api call in life cycle method `componentDidMount` and when api call returns some data set it to your state and let your user interface update accordingly.

E.g your api call method may be like this -

```
ApiCall() {
    return $.ajax({
       url: 'http://ip:port/allstudents',      
       type: 'GET',
    }).fail((responseData) => {
        if (responseData.responseCode) {
            console.error(responseData.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

After new data is fetched from server set the state with new data

```
this.setState({data:newDataFromServer});
```

Basically above call will return you a jquery promise which you can use later.

Now in what ever method you want to make ApiCall just use like this -

```
class App extends Component {

 constructor() {
   this.state = {
      data : []
   }
 }
 componentDidMount()
 {
   this.getFunction();
 }

 getFunction = () => {
     this.ApiCall()
        .then(
            function(data){
              console.log(data);
              // set the state here
              this.setState({data:data});
            },
            function(error){
              console.log(error);
           }
    );
 }

 render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <button id='b1'
           style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}}
           onClick={() => this.Getfunction()}>
        Get!
     </button>
     {/* Now render your data here using jsx if it is array iterate over it */}
    </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out